# How can I get my Remote Desktop App to write to local file

Tags: windows-7, permissions, desktop, remote, visual-foxpro

I have a remote desktop app running under Windows 7 Ultimate that writes a report. It would be much easier if the report could be written directly to the local machine.

How can I do this? every time I try I seem to run into permissions problems. If I try to write by explicit reference the folder (eg\Computer\Drive$\Folder\Subfolder\filename) it seems to work but its cumbersome and it would be easier if the user could select his own directory but use a standard sharename.

But, when I try to write by reference to its share name (reports) (eg \Computer\Sharename\filename) I get a file access error

Any suggestions on how I can get the share name to work?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the share name reference fails is likely due to the permissions - check them and that should work.

However another way is to just enable access to the local resources in the remote connection options - you can choose to share drives, printers and other items directly with the remote system. Once you've done this you'll find it in my computer, and be able to save directly.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  
Yes I thought it was permissions but as far as I could see 'everyone' had read/write permissions to the various directories. I currently have a workaround using full paths so the immediate crisis is passed but I would prefer shares.

And the challenge is programatically identifying, checking and writing (as opposed to hunting down in explorer)
.